# Mac OSX Terminal Setting PHP path not permanent

Tags: php, macos, terminal

I've got a MAC OSX (Capitan to be precise).

I have installed PHP7 by using this line of code in the terminal:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.0
```

After it installed I run this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH
```

After this when I run:

PHP -v

I get PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 31 2016 10:25:51) ( NTS )...

when is what I need it to do, so great BUT my problem is that as soon as I close my terminal and I run PHP -v again I get PHP 5.5

Why doesn't it keep PHP 7.0 ?

Comment: Because... hmmmm... you're exporting a path to the ... lets see ... php5 binary?

Comment: check this link http://serverfault.com/questions/124423/what-is-the-export-command-supposed-to-do-in-linux.

Comment: and here is how to change it https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2607040?tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

Add `export PATH=/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH` to your `~/.profile` dotfile so that the `PATH` variable is exported when you start your system (requires restart).

Or add it to `~/.bashrc` file so that it gets exported when you start you start bash.

I recommend using `~/.profile`.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced that the system has to be restarted.  The terminal program probably needs to be restarted, though you can use `bash -l` to start a shell with login processing — this is for testing (because you can exit and get back to your previous shell still), or `exec bash -l` if you're sure the new settings are OK (replaces your current shell with a new one).

Comment: In some cases you don't need to restart, and you can of course reload in other ways too. The easiest way to be sure is to restart. If you just add it to your `bashrc` file you only need to restart the terminal, because the `bashrc` is loaded everytime you start the terminal. The `~/.profile` file is only loaded once during startup and perhaps in a few other more complicated cases. If in doubt, a restart will be sure to make the new path sticky.